# How to integrate new language & compiler into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm working with a manufacturer that has their own Pascal based language, compiler and editor.  I'd like to investigate how feasible it would be to integrate their tools into Eclipse to get basics such as keyword highlighting, code completion, source navigation and of course compile to target to work.

Can anyone point me to a resource that explains how this can be done, if at all?

Thank you,
Fred

Answer (score 2):

IBM has an article series: [Create a commercial-quality Eclipse IDE](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-ecl-commplgin1/). Delving directly into Part 2 should give you a quick overview where to start.